# slowness when starting JHIPSTER application

Tags: spring, swagger, jhipster

I created a jhipster application and many entities, but the problem is when starting the application, it remains stuck for 6 min, the last message in the console is "started swagger", then continues the startup. is there a solution to this problem please?

Comment: about 20 entities, i didn't try disabling swagger, but can the probleme came from swagger? or an other dependencies that are used by jhipster?

Comment: See if there's any deadlock.

Comment: 20 entities is not a lot, some JHipster apps have 120 entities. Look at the timestamp of the log statements, you should be able to detect which step takes too much time, so far there's no evidence this si due to swagger. Springfox builds swagger-ui spec at startup time and it could be slow but not as slow as what you are experiencing. What are the characteristics of your PC? It could be a timeout, try setting DEBUG level for all loggers to see if you can detect which phase is going slow.

Comment: i lauched the app on 3 different computer with hight performance, so it's not the case. I will look in the logs and check, is there a way to get more detailed log, more than the default one?

Comment: how can i know if there a deadLock?

Comment: Same problem here, 6 minutes to start Swagger, stuck on log "org.jboss.threads                        : JBoss Threads version 3.1.0.Final" for 6 minutes. During that time the app is usable, but not the Swagger parts.